# Bubble Sort for link list not working properly

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to bubble sort the link list. But my code for some reason in not giving any output. 
I have tried to print the values too but for some reason, I am not getting any output. 
I am simply running two loops as we do in the array, but I am not able to figure out the error. 
The insertion part is correct.
Please help me with the code.

````
using namespace std; 
#define mod 1000000007
#define fast ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL); cout.tie(NULL);
#define endl "\n" 
typedef long long int ll;

class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;

        Node(int d){
            data = d;
            next = NULL;
        }
};

void swap(Node *ptr1, Node *ptr2){
    Node *temp = ptr2->next;
    ptr2->next = ptr1;
    ptr1->next = temp;
}

void bubbleSort(Node* &head, int n){
    Node *i = head;
    Node *j = head;
    while(i != NULL){
        while(j->next != NULL){
            if(j->data > j->next->data){
                swap(i, j->next);
            }
            j = j->next;
        }
        j = head;
        i = i->next;
    }
}

void insertAtRear(Node *&head, Node* &tail, int data){
    if(head == NULL){
        head = tail = new Node(data);
    }
    else{
        Node *n = new Node(data);
        n->next = NULL;
        tail->next = n;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
}

void printLinkList(Node* head){
    // Node *temp = head;
    while(head != NULL){
        cout << head->data << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    fast;
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int k; cin >> k;
        insertAtRear(head, tail, k);
    }

    bubbleSort(head, n);
    printLinkList(head);

    // while(head != NULL){

    // }
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your program in a debugger to see what happens? It may be easier if you remove the `cin` loop and replace it with one or two hardcoded calls to `insertAtRear`

Comment: The insertion part is correct. But there is some error in the bubbleSort function. I am not able to figure out how to keep track of head.

Comment: OK, so there's some information that should be in the question. Can you edit it in?  Now, hard-code two inserts (since no-one can reproduce your problem if the program is interactive and you haven't told us what input you gave it) guaranteeing that the head element will need to be swapped. Step through your sort function and think about what it needs to do in this case.

Comment: Discuss `while(j->next != NULL)` with your [Rubber Duck.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) Make sure you cover what you are testing for and what you aren't.

Comment: BTW, the macros you defined so not speed up execution nor compilation times.  I highly recommend not using macros as synonyms or abbreviations.  Very difficult to read your program.  You may want to consider taking a keyboarding class.

Comment: You've got a conflict of interest.  The `std` namespace contains the symbol `endl`.  You have `using namespace std;`, so the `endl` is in the global namespace.  This may conflict with your macro `endl`.

Comment: BTW, you and make your program more efficient by maintaining a pointer to the last node in the list.  This will save more time than tieing the input and output streams.